# R - Import .dat files into R, which are not delimited

Tags: r, import

I'm trying to import a **.dat** file into R. **The file is not delimited**
Therefore i need to specify the position and type for each variable.
In SAS, I can do this with a code that looks like this.

```
DATA imported_data; 
INFILE " C:\dataset.dat"
INPUT 
Var1 $ 1-2
Var2 $ 3-8
Var3 9-18
Var4 19-20
; 
RUN;
```

The variables Var1 and Var2 are character ($) and their position is 1-2, and 3-8 within the data file.

Is there a R code that can be used in same way to import the file to R?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with readr's `read_fwf` ([read fixed width file](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_fwf.html)).

```r
library(readr)

data <- read_fwf("C:\dataset.dat",
                 col_positions = fwf_positions(start = c(1, 3, 9, 19),
                                               end = c(2, 8, 18, 20)))
```

`read_fwf` will try to figure out the types of each column, but if there are mistakes you can specify the types yourself using the `col_types` argument.